# How to read worldedit .schem file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, minecraft

I'm trying to make a node application that uploads .schem files but I don't know how to use the fs import to read the file without modifying it. When I try to read and write the file again the data gets modified and world edit in minecraft can't read it.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you explain more ? Like show your code, how you get/upload the schem file ... Please [edit] your question :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Schematic_file_format#:%7E:text=The%20.,on%20the%20Indev%20level%20format.) the .schem files are saved using NBT, and its structure.

the nbt format is using binary format (comparing to json that you can read and modify easily). so you probably want to use an existing library, i have never programed in node.js but i found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nbt), if it helps